# Discord.py. Как можно одновременно ставить реакции и принимать их нажатия

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, discord-api

Необходимо как-то реализовать одновременную расстановку реакций и их принятие. Т.е бот ставит на какое-либо сообщение 3 реакции. Как только он поставил первую, а пользователь на нее нажал **прежде** чем бот завершил расстановку остальных, происходит какое-либо действие.

Проблема в том, что если реализовывать это через bot.wait_for - расстановка реакций встанет.
А если реализовать через ивент нажатия на реакцию, то можно будет активировать реакцию вне необходимого мне промежутка времени.

Comment: Уверен, что предварительная расстановка реакций от бота у вас ставится последовательно в синхронном режиме, поэтому долго расставляется. Ставьте их параллельно в асинхронном режиме.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В этом случае следует выделить боту отдельную функцию-событие, пометив ее соответствующим декоратором `@bot.event`

Событие добавления реакции в `Discord.py` называется `on_raw_reaction_add(payload)` и принимает в качестве аргумента `payload`. Из этого аргумента можно получить **эмоджи, ID пользователя, канала, сервера, сообщения** и [другую информацию](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_raw_reaction#discord.RawReactionActionEvent).

---

Создадим команду `add_reactions()`, при вызове которой бот будет добавлять на только что отправленное сообщение реакции из списка. В глобальную переменную запишем id этого сообщения, чтобы работать с ним при срабатывании `on_raw_reaction_add()`. *Либо можно записывать id сообщения в глобальный список, если нужно обрабатывать несколько сообщений.*

В коде `on_raw_reaction_add()` обрабатываем как надо полученную реакцию.

**Код:**

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents = discord.Intents.all())

msg = None

@bot.command()
async def add_reactions(ctx):
    global msg
    msg = ctx.message.id
    for emoji in ['1️⃣', '2️⃣', '3️⃣','4️⃣', '5️⃣', '6️⃣']:
        await ctx.message.add_reaction(emoji)

@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    if (payload.message_id == msg) and (payload.user_id != bot.user.id):
        channel = bot.get_channel(payload.channel_id)
        await channel.send(f'Получена реакция: {str(payload.emoji)}')

bot.run(TOKEN)
```